# How can I add a border to all the elements that share a class when the mouse has hovered over one of them?

Tags: html, css, class, html-table

Is it possible to change the border (or other style elements) of multiple table cells that all belong to class "xyz" by hovering over one, using only HTML and CSS?

I've got two dynamically generated tables. In this particular instance, one is 5 cells wide and 4 cells high, and the other table is 4 by 3.

There are:

- 2 cells in the first table that belong to class "xyz";
- 1 cell in the second table that belongs to class "xyz".

**Table 1:**

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |xyz |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |xyz |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

**Table 2:**

```
+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |xyz |
+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+
```

What I can do is:

- get all "xyz" cells formatted with a particular border;
- get one "xyz" cell to update it's style on hover ( td.xyz:hover {...} ).

What I can't do is:

- get all cells belonging to "xyz" to update their style when hovering over one.

Is it possible to do this using only HTML and CSS?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. You would have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CSS only works with **sibling** or **child** elements. Table cells **in the same row** are adjacent siblings, but cells in other rows others are not. Therefore you need to use JavaScript to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery solution would be:

```
$('.cellToHover').hover(function() {
    $('.cellToHover').addClass('hovered');
}, function() {
    $('.cellToHover').removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RU9X8/).

Comment: I believe the OP asked for an HTML/CSS solution.

Comment: @Bernie: He did, and he got the right answer, 2 times. I just was in the mood to give him an alternative solution if it would be an option for him too. ;-)

Comment: fair enough, didn't see your comment on the question initially. Apologies.

Comment: I'll probably use this. I just didn't want to include jquery if it wasn't necessary. Thanks!

Comment: @user2166884: If it is just jQuery you don't want to use, you can do this with plain JavaScript, but it's a bit less comfortable.